# Link directly to a specific store view?

Tags: store-view, magento2.2

I'm currently running Magento 2.2.1 and want to create links to a specific store view.

Each store view is translated to a certain language, and I'd like that links placed on blogs written in that language go directly to the respective store view.

I've tried adding the __store=pt query parameter but in Magento 2 this doesn't seem to work. Apparently the store switcher uses a POST call, which I can't do if I'm linking from another site.

Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked this out. It certainly is more complex than it should be but it works.

The problem is that passing the "__store" query param isn't enough for Magento to send the store cookie back. So I do it myself via rewrites.

Instead of using links of the form `http://example.com/some/magento/path/?__store=pt` I use `http://example.com/pt/some/magento/path/`.

Then I have an Apache Rewrite rule to redirect to the correct URL (without the pt in the path): `http://example.com/some/magento/path/` and send the cookie back.

Here's what that rewrite looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]

RewriteRule ^/pt/(.*) %{ENV:proto}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?__store=pt [R,L,QSA,CO=store:pt:;:60:/:HttpOnly]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of things in magento

1. Store
2. Store View

If you want to create the link of the **Store** then you need to follow these points:-

- a) First you need to create the folder on the root with the same name
  where your want to redirect. For example :

> http://hostname/projectname/storeName

and storeName is your folder name

- b) Then you need to create the file index.php and .htaccess under
  that folder.  .htaccess is files is the same file which is on your
  root, you just need to copy that file and place them under this
  folder.
- c) In the index.php file, you need to add this code

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require _DIR_ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/* @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app \/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require _DIR_ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;

 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'YOUR STORE CODE'; //Webite code as same in admin panel

 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';

 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

 /* @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app /

 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

 $bootstrap->run($app);

 ?>




----------
```

- d) Then you need to create symlink of pub/var/lib folder under this
  folder.
- e) Then last you need to add the URL through admin Choose your store
  -> Web -> base urls  like

> http://hostname/projectname/foldername

which you created on root

**AND**

**If you want to do via Store View then you need to follow this approach.**

a) This is only used if you want to change the language only.
b) Then you need to change the one setting through the admin

> Choose your store -> Configuration-> General -> Local option -> Choose
>   your language via local option

But make sure, after implement any step please flush the cache.

Please let me know if I was able to answer your questions.

Comment: I'm just using store views for each language. I believe that you're explaining me how to choose a different locale per store view, correct? I've already done that.